# Function calling itself based upon regular expression

Tags: php, regex, function

I have the requirement to create a UID and, given the first few components 
 - sections between the periods (.) -  I've created a function to do this. Generating this UID has a rule that it can't have any leading zeros in a component unless it's a zero in it's own component. Therefore:  *1.2.6.4.0.123.6653* is just fine, whereas *1.2.6.4.**0**123.6653* is not.

My function is as follows:

```
function genUid($type, $serverId){
    $prefix = '1.2.3.3680043.19.1944';
    $ts = date('YmdHis'); 
    $uniqid = substr(hexdec(uniqid()),-7);

    $uid = $prefix . '.' . $serverId . $type . '.' . $ts . '.' . $uniqid;

    // the uniqid can't start with a leading 0 
    //$re = '/\.0\d]/';
    $re = '/\.0[0-9]/';
    preg_match($re, $uid, $matches);
    if(count($matches)){
        genUid($type, $serverId);
    }
    return $uid;
}
```

and I simply call it via

```
for($i=0; $i<100000; $i++){
    $id = genUid('3', '1');
    echo $id . '<br>';
}

echo '<hr>Longest run circa 86,000';
```

When I run the script, it shows the 100,000 UIDs. To check I search for a period, followed by a zero and then any other number, 1 to 9. All looks just fine, until I then think to check ".00" in which case there always seems to be just one that's generated.

As you can see, the function should call itself if it finds that it's created a UID which matches the regular expression '/.0\d/' (I tried '/.0[0-9]/' too to see if it made any difference, which it didn't) but it always seems to create no more than one UID which fails the UID naming rules.

The script isn't timing out (takes about 5 sec to complete) so I'm a little baffled as to why either the function isn't calling itself properly, or my regular expression is incorrect? IMHO, it should never create a UID that breaks the rules.

Can anyone give me some guidance as to why it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` the value of the function when you call it recursively:

```
if(count($matches)){
    return genUid($type, $serverId);
}
```

In a general sense, it looks like you're making an id from integers separated by `.` characters. May I suggest the [`gettimeofday`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettimeofday.php) and [`mt_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) functions? `gettimeofday` will give you the current time as two integers (seconds since the epoch, and microseconds in the second), and `mt_rand` will generate a random integer between two values. By using integers, you don't need to check for leading zeroes. Something like this might work for you:

```
function genUid($type, $serverId){
    $prefix = '1.2.3.3680043.19.1944';
    $time = gettimeofday();
    $random = mt_rand(0, 9999999);
    $uid = sprintf(
        '%s.%d.%d.%d.%d.%d',
        $prefix,
        $serverId,
        $type,
        $time['sec'],
        $time['usec'],
        $random
    );
    return $uid;
}
```

Please note that `uniqid` and `mt_rand` are not cryptographically secure, should that be a requirement in your project.

Comment: It would appear that it was the missing "return" that was causing my issues. I've just performed a 500,000 run, and none of the UIDs have errors. Many thanks @astrangeloop!

(and thanks for the suggestions ... I'll certainly consider them and run some timing tests to see how they fair against my existing code - I've heard that running regexs can be time consuming, so speeding anything up is going to be an advantage)